# How to Get CPU usage for each VM on ESXI host

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, cpu-usage, vsphere, esxi

I want to get CPU usage (cumulative) for each VM hosted on a VMware ESXI host.

I tried using Power CLI command 'Get-VMHost' but it only gives the overall CPU usage by ESXI host.

Answer (score 0):

For CPU usage esxtop is a very powerful ESX command and you have to run it at the CLI.  I haven't used the Power CLI so I'm unsure if it's available there but it is definitely available at the CLI which VMware tries to discourage you from using (see https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2004746).  Documentation for esxtop for the latest release of vSphere is at https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/7.0/com.vmware.vsphere.monitoring.doc/GUID-D89E8267-C74A-496F-B58E-19672CAB5A53.html.

That document is a bit terse and in terms of getting CPU usage for each VM this old documentation for esxtop may guide you a bit better https://www.vmware.com/pdf/esx2_using_esxtop.pdf.  In particular note the different nomenclature of ESXi (and ESX) for which the primary unit of address space and execution is the "world" rather than the "process".  Thus you want to get the CPU usage for all "worlds" associated with each VM.  Some VMs may have only a single "world" and some may have several and it is configurable.  As for esxtop, it has been around forever and most likely it can still today provide the same functionality that it did over a decade ago with ESX 2.